# Why do i need this curly braces here? Can anybody explain me why does this happens?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gdi+

I'm making a code to make a screenshot and save it in a JPEG file type. I found this piece of code but I don't understand why it gives me an error when I remove curly braces after 
`GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);`.

Full code:

```
void gdiscreen()
{
    using namespace Gdiplus;
    GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
    ULONG_PTR gdiplusToken;
    GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);
    {
        HDC scrdc, memdc;
        HBITMAP membit;
        scrdc = ::GetDC(0);
        int Height = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);
        int Width = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
        memdc = CreateCompatibleDC(scrdc);
        membit = CreateCompatibleBitmap(scrdc, Width, Height);
        HBITMAP hOldBitmap = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(memdc, membit);
        BitBlt(memdc, 0, 0, Width, Height, scrdc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
        Gdiplus::Bitmap bitmap(membit, NULL);
        CLSID clsid;
        GetEncoderClsid(L"image/jpeg", &clsid);
        bitmap.Save(L"screen.jpeg", &clsid);
        SelectObject(memdc, hOldBitmap);
        DeleteObject(memdc);
        DeleteObject(membit);
        ::ReleaseDC(0, scrdc);
    }
    GdiplusShutdown(gdiplusToken);
}
```

Can somebody explain to me why I need the curly braces?

And when I remove the curly braces it gives me the following error:

```
Exception produced in 0x661AF6B8 (GdiPlus.dll) in DebugScreenShotModule.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation when reading location 0x029E12AC.
```

Comment: These are sometimes called "scoping braces".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a variable `Gdiplus::Bitmap bitmap` declared within the curly braces.  It will be destroyed at the closing `}`.  Without the curly braces, it won't be destroyed until *after* `GdiplusShutdown` is called.

Comment: You mean that if i declare some variables in a block inside a void, when the block finish it will get destroyed?

Comment: @KAoTI Yes, that is. Although I am not sure what you mean by "inside a void". The function return type has nothing to do with it. You can create nested scopes as much as you want.

Comment: Yeah, sorry by "inside a void"  i refer to a whatever function!